# c++ creating an array of object in a function need to use the array in global scope

Tags: c++

Hello I'm trying to implement a Extendible Hashtable. 
My Problem is: I have an add function where i decide when to splitt a bucket and if i splitt it how many new buckets i need. So i create after an if statment an array of objects. So far no problems, now i want to print the array in a other function called:

`std::ostream& print(std::ostream& o)`

this is a function which is overloading the << operator as you can see in the Headerfile Container:

```
virtual std::ostream& print(std::ostream& o) const = 0;
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Container<E>& c) { return c.print(o); }
```

So now my add function follows:

```
template <typename E>
void ExHashing<E>::add(const E e[], size_t len) {
    if(isfirstBucket(head)){
        fill_first_bucket(head, last, e,len,bucket);
    }
    else {
        int number = 2;
        Bucket<E> buckets = new Bucket<E>(number);
        Bucket<E>* bucket_Pointer = buckets[1];
        bucket_Pointer->Set_local_depth(1);
    }
}
```

You can see that i make an array of Bucket objects which is working fine i can just not print them out in my print function because buckets is not defined there. My Print function:

```
template <typename E>
std::ostream& ExHashing<E>::print(std::ostream& o) const {
    size_t number_of_buckets = (1 << global_depth);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < number_of_buckets; ++i) {
        o << "Bucket size = " << buckets->bucket_size; << "  " << "Bucket index = " << buckets[i]->index << "  " << "Global depth = " << global_depth << " " << "Local depth = " << buckets[i]->local_depth << "\n";
        for (size_t j = 0; j < buckets[i]->bucket_size; ++j) {
            o << " Bucket value " << "[" << j << "]" << " = " << buckets[i]->displayValues(j)<<"\n";
        }
    }
    return o;
}
```

So how do give my print function acces to the array buckets? I can't add a parameter to function print since i just receives the comad print from the shell an should show my data in the buckets. Where do i initialise my array? I can't do it in the Constructor since i don't know how many data someone is going to put in i have to do inside the programm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Containers store the necessary entry points to the held data as members of the object. In your case, you'd store the pointer to the buckets (and any other administrative data you'll need):

```
template <typename E>
class ExHashing {
    Bucket<E>* buckets;
public:
    ExHashing(): buckets(0) {}               // Make sure the pointer is initialized.
    ExHashing(ExHashing const&);             // You'll likely need a copy ctor,
    ~ExHashing();                            // a destructor,
    ExHashing& operator= (ExHashing const&); // and copy assignment.
    // as well as other mmebers
};
```

When you create or access your buckets you'd use `this->buckets` instead of a local variable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One more question shouldn't i make the Copyconstructor and the opy assignemnt in my class Bucket since i want to change the bucket tu an bigger array?

Comment: @Thor: the class template `Bucket` may also need to implement these operations. Since you allocate a pointer to `Bucket<E>` you'll need to release it, i.e., you'll have destructor `delete`ing the object. The generated copy operations will just copy the pointer and you'd get double `delete`s for an object. So, you need to either define them or, at least, disable them. BTW, the relevant "currency" at Stackoverflow isn't "thanks" but upvotes and accepts. ... and questions are meant to be, well, questions not comments: I'm pretty sure a similar question was answered in the past.